# Xform class in Oracle JavaFX tutorial?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

I'm following along with an official tutorial for constructing basic JavaFX 3D applications, and would like to understand what I'm looking at.  As such I have a few related questions.

The tutorial is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/sampleapp3d.htm#BABBIEAC

First of all, the Xform class is pretty confusing.  I guess that basically all it is is a wrapper for Translates, Rotates, and Scales.  But it has three Translates and I can't understand why.  Their names, `t`, `p`, and `ip`, aren't meaningful to me.

Secondly, the way its used in MoleculeSampleApp also doesn't make much sense.  There are three `cameraXforms`, and I can't understand why there are so many.  It seems like only one should be necessary, because Xform contains all of the transforms.  It seems like in the tutorial, `cameraXform` is used for rotation and `cameraXform2` is used for translation.  So it's not clear why it needs both.  But even more confusing, `cameraXform3` appears to do nothing at all.  Is there a purpose to this that I'm missing?

Thanks for any help you can give on correcting my thinking!